# Polymorphism and local variables

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am creating several threads that will collect data from the database.

However in all of these threads i will need a local reference to my `Database` object as far as i know there are two ways of doing this either i use an interface:

```
public interface Command {
void execute();
void collectData();
void processData();
void setData(ArrayList<Objects> data);
```

}

And then set the variable manually in each of the thead classes (that extends the command interface)

However doing my test and search i found that i could do the following:

```
public abstract class commandtest implements Runnable{
    Database db;
    abstract void execute();
    abstract void collectData();
    abstract void processData();
    abstract void setData(ArrayList<Objects> data);
}
```

Here by have an abstract class that each of my thread objects can extend and then create a constructor to set the variables needed.

My question is rather simple which of these two methods is the best pratice?

Comment: There's no "best", there's what's "best for the situation".

Comment: @DaveNewton How do i decide this? what factors should i take into consideration?

Comment: I would have the interface declared and an abstract class that implements the interface that has a `protected Database db` attribute,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not decide on placement of variables based solely on the need to share some code or some variables. If your abstract class is designed with the idea that everything extending it *must* have access to `Database`, then you put `Database` in the base class.

On the other hand, if some of the intended implementations would have nothing to do with the database, then you should not add `Database` to the abstract base class. Of course you are not limited to just two levels of the inheritance hierarchy: you can always start with `commandtest` that does not have `Database`, and add another level of abstract classes for everything that does need a database:

```
abstract class AbstractCommandTest {
    abstract void execute();
    abstract void collectData();
    abstract void processData();
    abstract void setData(ArrayList<Objects> data);
    // Other methods shared by all commands
}
abstract class AbstractDatabaseCommandTest extends AbstractCommandTest {
    protected Database db;
    protected AbstractDatabaseCommandTest(Database db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
}
class SomeCommandThatDoesNotNeedDatabase extends AbstractCommandTest {
    ...
}
class DatabaseCommand1 extends AbstractDatabaseCommandTest {
    ...
}
class DatabaseCommand2 extends AbstractDatabaseCommandTest {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that

> in all of these threads i will need a local reference to my Database
>   object

your second approach seems appropriate.
I would declare the `db` variable as private since it is going to be different per thread (that is what i felt from your question). Else it could be mistaken to be shared across implementing classes.

```
private Database db;
```

and expose an `abstract setDatabase(Database database)` method so each implementing class sets its database.

Comment: Funny you should mention this after i looked it over again i did just that nicely spotted.